# Microcontroller memory dump

Tags: firmware, memory-dump

I have a board which has **STM32F103RE** microcontroller. Its datasheet can be found [here](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103ze.pdf).

Since I have found in the internet only firmware that seems to be encrypted/compressed, I'm trying to figure out how to dump it from the flash (using logic analyzer or Bus Pirate, etc.).

Can someone please help me out with this challenge?
Elaborated answer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The protocol you would use here is called JTAG, which I'm assuming your Bus Pirate will be able to handle. I don't have experience with this particular microcontroller, but if I were you I'd look into OpenOCD as a tool.

Comment: @felixphew: please use the answer box for answers. comments should be  used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I didn’t feel that qualified as an answer, more as advice to OP on where to look (it doesn’t really answer the question) hence I hesitated to post it as an answer.

Comment: even an incomplete answer is better than a comment which is not a comment, and it can be improved later. Please read https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment